# What is the architecturally correct and secure way to expose business logic to a task scheduling mechanism

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks

I have a three tier asp.net web app backed by SQL server express, with business logic in C#, and a web UI.  I have a small collection of actions that exist as methods on objects in my business logic layer that need to run on a configurable, periodic basis.  These actions rely on many other objects in my current app along with needing my data access layer to talk to SQL.  Currently I manually log in to the admin site and kick off the actions via my UI as there are only two at the moment but that will grow.

A couple options I've considered but wanted thoughts on before I proceed...

I could create some scheduled tasks in Windows server to kick these actions off periodically but I want to know how would I expose these actions in the best way.  I thought of creating a web service exposing them and building a tiny exe to call that web service but I would have to make sure that web service was locked down with security.  Another option which I know a little less about would be exposing those actions via export and then building an app that could use them by referencing the DLL.  It seems that app would get kind of large if it has to pull everything in to use unless I could componentize my app binaries more so it would only need a small binary or two.

Any thoughts on how I should approach this or pointers on content discussing this type of issue?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to expose the scheduled tasks to a service? Why can't they just run periodically? If you want a manual override why can't you call them like you do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had gone the way of tiny EXE that calls a WebService from main app and it seems to work well, but that was before I discovered Quartz.net.

Now I'd suggest use [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/features.html) as a scheduler. From the site:

- Jobs can be any .NET class that implements the simple IJob interface,
  leaving infinite possibilities for the work Jobs can perform.